# How to backup issues list from Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket, issue-tracking

With issues gathering on bitbucket, I'd like to have a way to gather and back them up in the event that I need an offline copy, or no longer use Bitbucket, or something else.  The site doesn't offer this service. Is there an alternative mechanism I can use?

Answer (score 12):

[From now on you can Import/Export your Issues:](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/04/02/finnovation-brings-you-a-heap-of-new-features/)
Goto: -> Administration -> Import/Export

Youtube-Video: [Bitbucket Issue Export](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qm9dCE9GE4)

Comment: This is only useful to import back into BitBucket. The question is clearly about having a 'usable' offline copy in case he wants to no longer use BitBucket (or other simple uses like communicating the list of open issues to someone by email). Something simple like a CSV export would have been great to import in an Excel sheet or something useful by humans.

Comment: Yes, and the output format is JSON, which can be simply parsed. Have a look at: https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=293830712. It is possible to import this data without using Bitbucket. So it is usable. He did not specify what output format he prefer or what he tries to achieve.

Comment: If it has to be parsed no its not really usable by humans. Typical programmer attitude. JSON is not a human readable format, it is a machine format, unless Excel or one of the tools common mortals use supports it. If the user is just a client who wishes to export to a readable format for offline use he needs it to be in a format common tools can open. He did not specify what output  format he needed but there is something called common sense.

Comment: And by reimporting to JIRA Issue Tracking it is humanreadable. But it's okay ;)

Comment: But why are you assuming that who is using BitBucket has JIRA? And what's more than that available offline? If one had JIRA available (which supports Excel export, but obviously its a much more powerful commercial product) he wouldn't need to use BitBucket for his issues at all.

Answer (score 10):

You can get your issues via the Bitbucket API.

Here is an example URL to get the issues for one of my projects:
https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/christianspecht/bitbucket-backup/issues/

However, this returns a list of the issues in JSON format.
I doubt that you can do anything useful with a list of issues in JSON, but I don't know if there's a better file format for issues.

I just asked exactly that here on StackOverflow, because I'm dealing with the same thing at the moment:
[Is there a standard file format for exporting issues from an issue tracker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205108/is-there-a-standard-file-format-for-exporting-issues-from-an-issue-tracker)

Comment: Cool. Here is the documentation for that API: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/issues

Answer (score 3):

Full disclosure I am the author of [Issue2Markdown](https://github.com/yepher/Issues2Markdown) because I really needed it.

As mentioned previously you can export your issues from Bitbucket project by going to *Settings->Issues->Import & Export* and then downloading the resultant ZIP file.

Inside that ZIP file, you will find JSON file and attachments archive. You can import those into some other issue repository. Or if you are like me you may be working with a remote team that is reluctant to use an issue tracker and would like to be able to read a human-readable version of the issues.

That is where [Issue2Markdown](https://github.com/yepher/Issues2Markdown) comes in. You can use that to render your issues as a single Markdown document. You can find pre-built binaries for Linux, Windows, and MacOS under [releases](https://github.com/yepher/Issues2Markdown/releases).

I hope that helps the next person who could not find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't currently appear to be any way to export your issues :(

Answer (score 2):

You could export issues from `settings` in the repository. Then download the and extract the zip file, that would give you a json that you just could parse any way you prefer

I wrote a small python script to convert issues json file to excel that you can find it here. Hope it gives you some ideas:

https://github.com/anath2/bitbucket-issues-to-excel