# How to automatically do full backup of repo, wiki, issue tracker etc. in bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I hope my computer can do full backup of a project hosted on bitbucket.org, including all of repo, wiki, issue tracker. How to do it automatically?

Answer (score 3):

bitbucket backup https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/bitbucket-backup/downloads
will backup your repos and wiki's  but its windows only and doesn't grab issues

seems to work quite well. Been using it for a month

Comment: "This repository has been deleted"

Comment: This repository has been deleted
Our apologies, but the repository "christianspecht/bitbucket-backup" has been deleted.

It now lives at https://christianspecht.de/bitbucket-backup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to grab everything, automatically using nothing but bitbucket itself (there's no "Download Backup" link).  You may want to take a look at [this tool](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/bitbucket-backup) though.  It looks like it can at least grab the repository and wiki, but not issues--although it could be made to backup issues using the bitbucket api.

You can see more about backing up issues here: [How to backup issues list from Bitbucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925832/how-to-backup-issues-list-from-bitbucket)

In short, there doesn't appear to be a tool to help do everything that you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to clone both the source code repository and the wiki (without special tools). For instance:

Cloning the repository:

```
git clone [your repository uri]
```

Cloning the wiki:

```
git clone [your repository uri]/wiki
```

Note: Cloning the repository won't automatically clone your wiki! Also, this does not include your issues!

Comment: Be careful if you're using this to backup a repository. `git clone` only creates one local branch, `master` by default, which tracks the `master` branch on the remote repository. You would miss backing up all other branches.